# GWT, NoSuchElement exception

Tags: java, javascript, gwt

We are using GWT in a big project.
In some cases this code can produce `NoSuchElementException`:

```
for (Object o: myList) {
}
```

There is no modification of ArrayList inside.

But this occurs very recently.

In source codes of generated application I found:

```
var context, context$iterator, operation;
operation = doDeserialize(this$static, ctx, json);
for (context$iterator =
    new java_util_AbstractList$IteratorImpl_AbstractList$IteratorImpl__Ljava_util_AbstractList_2V(this$static.jetbrains_jetpad_otmodel_ot_persistence_OperationPersistenceContext_myContextDelegates);
    context$iterator.java_util_AbstractList$IteratorImpl_i < context$iterator.java_util_AbstractList$IteratorImpl_this$0.size__I();
) {
    context = java_util_AbstractList$IteratorImpl_$next__Ljava_util_AbstractList$IteratorImpl_2Ljava_lang_Object_2(context$iterator);
}
```

So first this returns true: `iterator.i < iterator.size();` 
but in next line `(in .next())` this code also returns true: `iterator.i >= iterator.size();`

I can reproduce at in Chrome only.

Comment: If you think you found a bug, and assuming you're using the latest version, please file an issue at https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/entry

Comment: I'm a contributor to GWT, I'm not sure it is a bug, bcz I cannot realize how can it be :-(

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a bug in chrome's javascript implementation.  It occurs rarely in commonly run code paths, so I suspect it's a subtle timing issue. It has been happening since Chrome 29.0.1547.57.

Our customers have been seeing a few instances of this per day, for the last few releases of chrome.  But we haven't been able to reproduce it ourselves, nor can I find values that cause < and >= to behave this way.

Yours is the first evidence I've seen of someone else having this issue.

One wild guess is that the value of *i* isn't making its way from the prototype to the new object right away.  (We saw a similar issue in Firefox years ago.) You could try tweaking the `AbstractList$IteratorImpl` to set *i=0* explicitly in the constructor, this might be enough to keep the bug from triggering.  (We haven't tried this in production yet, we were hoping it'd get fixed upstream.)

We're seeing this in places like PopupPanel, which we haven't touched:

```
Object.java.lang.RuntimeException.RuntimeException()@89F75B80AAD5A61ED1288B1136D17E39.cache.html:3144
Object.java.util.NoSuchElementException.NoSuchElementException()@89F75B80AAD5A61ED1288B1136D17E39.cache.html:3247
java.util.AbstractList$IteratorImpl.$next()@89F75B80AAD5A61ED1288B1136D17E39.cache.html:6218
com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.PopupPanel.$eventTargetsPartner()@89F75B80AAD5A61ED1288B1136D17E39.cache.html:7593
com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.PopupPanel.$previewNativeEvent()@89F75B80AAD5A61ED1288B1136D17E39.cache.html:8326
```

Comment: I opened IteratorImpl: int i = 0, last = -1;
So I can not set it to 0, bcz it is already set

Comment: In javascript, that zero ends up in the prototype.  I'm suggesting that you add a constructor that sets it to 0 when the object is initialized.  That is, add  `public IteratorImpl() { i=0; }`  to the class. I'm not sure if it'll help, but it did work for a similar firefox issue in the past.  We're putting off trying this until our next release.

Comment: Yesterday, I pushed them a bug: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=297570&thanks=297570&ts=1380027626
And I replaced Gwt AbstractList emulation class in gwt-user. It was a really big hack bcz of using Maven, but it works

Comment: I don't use maven, but for patches to emul stuff I keep my own "super" directory tree, and place it in the compile-time class path before gwt-user.jar.  That way I can keep the GWT jars pristine.